# I'm a non-U.S. citizen that paid Social Security tax. I'm leaving the country. Can I get my money back?

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security, refund

I am not a U.S. citizen and I am leaving the country in a few months. Can I get the money back that I paid for Social Security taxes, since I am not going to be retiring in the United States?

Comment: My husband is a non-U.S. citizen that paid Social Security tax for 9 year while he worked in USA. He left the country many years ago, Is he entitle to get this money back at his retirement age?

Comment: @Rosi I think the current answer to this question answers that effectively.  If you have additional details (such as if your husband reached the benefits threshold) you may want to post a separate question.  You may also want to see [this brochure](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/pubs/EN-05-10137.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot. The FICA taxes paid are not refunded if you're not reaching the benefits threshold. They're gone. That is why foreigners who are not tax residents (mainly students) are not required to pay them.

If your home country has a social security reciprocity agreement with the US - you can have a credit in your home country.

Comment: "foreigners who are not tax residents (mainly students) are not required to pay them" Only non-residents in certain statuses (e.g. F-1, J-1) are exempt from FICA. Not all nonresidents.

Comment: @user102008 wasn't that what I said? F1 is a student status, J-1 is mostly a student or scholar status.

Comment: It sounded like you were saying that foreigners who are not tax residents are not required to pay them, and that foreigners who are not tax residents are mainly students. But maybe you meant it another way.

Comment: Foreigners who would be subjected to FICA had they been tax residents, yet don't have to pay it - are almost exclusively students (and other J1 holders - post-docs and such). Foreigners on L1/H1/L2/EAD in GC proceedings, and other employement eligible foreigners - are tax residents.