# What is the benefits threshold for social security tax

Tags: united-states, non-resident, social-security

I am a foreigner working in NY and will be leaving in few month.  I would like to know if I can get refund for the social security tax because I can't enjoy it.  I see [the answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/27169/25282) was "No, you cannot. The FICA taxes paid are not refunded if you're not reaching the benefits threshold. "

What is the amount for the benefits threshold? Do you mean if my past contribution is over the benefits threshold, I will be able to claim refund for social security tax when I leave US?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm a non-U.S. citizen that paid Social Security tax. I'm leaving the country. Can I get my money back?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27167/im-a-non-u-s-citizen-that-paid-social-security-tax-im-leaving-the-country-c)

Comment: While the other question has someone in the same circumstance, it does not address *what* the benefit threshold is.

Comment: I think what the other answer was trying to say is that the only way to "reclaim" some of the SS tax is by working 40 "quarters" AKA around 10 years so that you qualify for benefits at or near retirement age.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you mean if my past contribution is over the benefits threshold, I will be able to claim refund for social security tax when I leave US?

No.  If you meet the "benefits threshold" (and possibly meet other criteria), you will be able to claim Social Security when you retire.

The only time that you can get a refund for FICA tax is if it is inappropriately withheld in the first place.  However, that is a very specific set of circumstances that you probably don't meet.  If you were temporarily a tax resident of the United States, you had to pay FICA.  That's true even if you stopped being a tax resident.  You'd only get a refund if you weren't supposed to be a tax resident and your employer withheld inappropriately.

Benefits threshold is not an official term.  Officially, they talk about [Social Security credits](https://faq.ssa.gov/link/portal/34011/34019/Article/3829/How-do-I-earn-Social-Security-credits-and-how-many-do-I-need-to-qualify-for-benefits).  Someone may need to have up to forty credits to be eligible, and only four credits can be earned per year.  The forty credits would be the "benefits threshold" (unofficially, just as a thing to call it).